# Unable to use Vegan Package on Mac OSX catalina

Tags: r, package, cran, vegan

Is anyone able to help with the following error code or knows a different way to install the vegan package?

Tried both codes below... Need to do some MDS plots!

Code:

```
install.packages('vegan')

install.packages('vegan', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

Error Message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘vegan’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply using a (very!) old version of R. Update to the latest version and everything should work fine.